# Luaj attempt to index ? (a function value)

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I am trying to compile Lua code that has two functions which I want to invoke and get some information from but when I use invokemethod on the LuaValue object, I get this error

> LuaError: attempt to index ? (a function value)

The code is inside a LuaScript class I created for convenience

This method is first called to compile the file

```java
public void compile(File file) {
    try {
        Globals globals = JmePlatform.standardGlobals();
        compiledcode = globals.load(new FileReader(file), "script");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then this is used to invoke the function `getSameTiles` from my lua script

```java
public Object invoke(String func, Object... parameters) {
    if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
        LuaValue[] values = new LuaValue[parameters.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
            values[i] = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(parameters[i]);
        return compiledcode.invokemethod(func, LuaValue.listOf(values));
    } else
        return compiledcode.invokemethod(func);
}
```

The error `LuaError: attempt to index ? (a function value)` occurs at the line `return compiledcode.invokemethod(func);` where `"getSameTiles"` is passed as the string for `func`

This is my Lua code

```lua
function getSameTiles()
    --My code here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that needed fixing.

Firstly, in lua, `load()` returns a function which you'd then need to call to execute the script.

Secondly, what the script does is add a function to the global table `_G`. In order to invoke that function you'll need to get the function from the `Globals` table and call that.

The following code does this

```
Globals globals = JmePlatform.standardGlobals();

public void compile(File file) {
    try {
        globals.load(new FileReader(file), "script").call();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Object invoke(String func, Object... parameters) {
    if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
        LuaValue[] values = new LuaValue[parameters.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
            values[i] = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(parameters[i]);
        return globals.get(func).call(LuaValue.listOf(values));
    } else
        return globals.get(func).call();
}
```